# Triple DES (DES 3)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, 3des, tripledes

I'm trying to do an encrypt using 3DES the value from MD5 and key but the result always different than the online tool like this tool ( Online Domain Tools ) and always the length bigger than 32 characters so what the problem

Note: Value from md5 and key should be in HEX

```
public static class MacInGenerator
        {
            public static string GenerateMacIn(string customerId, string refid, string pAmount)
            {
                string macInInput = customerId + refid + pAmount;
                //log("macInInput ----> " + macInInput);

                string digitalSignature = ComputeMD5Hash(macInInput);
                //log("digitalSignature ----> " + digitalSignature);

                string encryptedMacIn = Encrypt3DES(digitalSignature, "key of 32 char and digit");
                //log("encryptedMacIn ----> " + encryptedMacIn);

                return encryptedMacIn;
            }


            static string ComputeMD5Hash(string input)
            {
                using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
                {
                    byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
                    byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("x2")); // Convert to hexadecimal
                    }

                    return stringBuilder.ToString();
                }
            }
            static string Encrypt3DES(string data, string keyHex)
            {
                using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider des3 = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
                {
                    des3.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keyHex);
                    des3.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                    des3.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

                    ICryptoTransform encryptor = des3.CreateEncryptor();
                    byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                    byte[] encryptedBytes = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);
                    var result = BitConverter.ToString(encryptedBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are stringifying the hex values of the byte array that you got from MD5, then hashing that. Why not just pass the byte array itself around? Side note: both MD5 and 3DES are insecure, and I can't anyway think of a point of using both one on top the other.